# Is it safe to pass properties as pointer-like arguments in a method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating a convenience method on my database controller class, which is intended to provide two sub-items for another item. This is what it looks like.

```
+ (void)getLeft:(out MySubItem *)left 
          right:(out MySubItem *)right 
        forItem:(MyItem *)item
{
    ...
    left = aResult;
    right = anotherResult;
}
```

In all instances where this method would be used, left and right are strong properties.

```
[Database getLeft:self.leftItem right:self.rightItem forItem:anItem];
```

Is there an issue with this? The Static Analyzer also complains because the declarations of left and right are never read (dead store), I'd like to be able to fix this...

Comment: Yes this is perfectly valid. It's not used very often these days, typically I'd use closures (blocks) instead now, but what you're doing is the older method and works perfectly fine - just need to get the syntax right as @KudoCC demonstrated.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert good idea on using blocks. Swift's tuples would be good here as well but that's not available to me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to change the value of self.leftItem, so you should use address of self.leftItem (it is MySubItem*) as parameter, so you should use `MySubItem **`.

Try it:

```
+ (void)getLeft:(out MySubItem **)p_left 
          right:(out MySubItem **)p_right 
        forItem:(MyItem *)item
{
    ...
    *p_left = aResult;
    *p_right = anotherResult;
}
```

and

```
MySubItem *l = nil ;
MySubItem *r = nil ;
[Database getLeft:&l right:&r forItem:anItem];
self.leftItem = l ;
self.rightItem = r ;
```

Updated: I found a solution which don't need two step... I think self.leftItem and self.rightItem is strong property, if not, use __weak instead.

```
+ (void)getLeft:(out NSObject * __strong *)p_left
          right:(out NSObject * __strong *)p_right
        forItem:(NSObject *)item
{
    *p_left = nil;
    *p_right = nil;
}
```

Can't use self.leftItem, use _leftItem instead.

`[Database getLeft:&_leftItem right:&_rightItem forItem:anItem];`

Comment: I get a compiler error: "Address of property expression required"

Comment: Thanks KudoCC. I was hoping to avoid this two step approach but it does indeed work!

Comment: @Ricky Updated again.

Comment: Nice one. I don't think this solution will work for regular variables. How come the * are separated here?

Comment: It means a pointer to a variable which has the type of (__strong NSObject *), if we omit __strong, it will be `__autoreleasing NSObject *` by default.

Comment: Pass by reference in this pattern is strongly discouraged in Objective-C.   In the vary rare case that it is used, you should always test to make sure the address being passed is non-nil.  In this case, you'll be better served by refactoring away from pass by reference.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd approach the same problem using blocks. The syntax is a bit uglier, but I also generally try to avoid pointers.

```
+ (void)valuesForItem(MyItem *)item completion:(void (^)(MySubItem *left, MySubItem *right))completion
{
  ...

  completion(l, r);
}

[Database valuesForItem:anItem completion:^void(MySubItem *left, MySubItem *right){
  self.leftItem = left;
  self.rightItem = right;
}];
```

Comment: The method should be renamed;  it is no longer a `get` method and that block really isn't a `completion` handler unless the operation is truly asynchronous, which should be unlikely.

Comment: @bbum thanks, you're right of course. Why not just edit my answer next time? :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**  As @JohnGibb mentions in the comments, a far better pattern is to not use lazy loading at all.   Lazy initialization, especially when it is a potentially very expensive, will incur non-determinate behavior that will likely need to be refactored later because it'll cause responsiveness hiccups or any number of other problems.

Far better to separate *loading* from *use* of the various items.

---

Don't use pass-by-reference.  And don't use a block (unless you are going to build a generic object graph traversal/visitation pattern where a "visitor" block is actually quite handy -- but that isn't called for here).

Add a `leftItem` and `rightItem` method to your `MyItem` class.   That avoids pass-by-reference, preserves encapsulation in that the `MyItem` class is now responsible for said relationships (including enabling overrides in subclasses), is straightforward and means that callers can easily chose to only get the left or right, as needed.

---

A more typical OO pattern:

```
@interface MyItem : SomeClass
@property(readonly) MySubItem *leftItem;
@property(readonly) MySubItem *rightItem;
@end

@implementation MyItem
- (void) loadUpDaStuff
{
   ... 
}

- (MySubItem*) leftItem
{
  if (self.notLoaded) [self loadUpDaStuff];
  return _leftItem;
}  

- (MySubItem*) rightItem
{
  if (self.notLoaded) [self loadUpDaStuff];
  return _rightItem;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if loading is really expensive, then use a load method + completion block.

Comment: I assume he has a good reason to do what he's doing? It's hard to judge coding style without knowing his real world use case.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Admittedly, I'm making an assumption.  But it is an assumption born out of many years of experience.  Unless OP comes back w/a justification for really truly thinking they need a pass-by-reference pattern, I'd be willing to bet that it is a misuse of patterns. :)

Comment: I chose this approach for two reasons. Firstly, there are (currently) no instances where the client uses just one sub item. I am doing a database lookup to get these sub items - so, secondly, I'd prefer to just be making one lookup rather than two.

Comment: @Ricky It should be an instance method and whether it requires one lookup or two (or five) should be an implementation detail of the class (i.e. calling `leftOne` might load both `left` and `right` and a subsequent call to `rightOne` returns the already retrieved value -- more importantly, calling `leftOne` five times doesn't incur 4 unnecessary accesses).

Comment: I personally don't like this approach, as I don't think models should have knowledge of a database. How are they going to maintain a connection? Is it obvious to a caller than a simple property access incurs a database penalty? Properties should usually just return an instance variable, or perform a very simple calculation based on instance variables (maybe returning a formatted string or something).